# How to remove last zeros in decimal

Tags: c#

I am trying to remove last zero of a decimal value search a lot for this but all answers in web and stack overflow removing all zeros. My aim to display some zeros in last.

```
Sample
50.00000000
50.01000000
50.01010000
50.01011000
50.01010100

expected 
    50.00
    50.01
    50.0101
    50.01011
    50.010101
```

I dont lnow how to do it in c#.

I was tried many things like `.ToString("G29")`; and other answers available but its all giving me like

```
50.00
50.01
50.01
50.01
50.01
```

Please Help..

Comment: have you tried the `0.00#########` format?

Comment: @Ivar 50.00 if no decimal fraction then it should be .00 in last

Comment: looking at the first desired result: 0.00#########

Comment: variable.TrimEnd('0')

Comment: Should input `50` result in output `50.00` ?

Comment: I agree with Alex and Erno de Weerd. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings to know how custom numeric format works :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
decimal num = 50.00m;
decimal num2 = 50.01010100m;
Console.WriteLine(num.ToString("0.00#########"));
Console.WriteLine(num2.ToString("0.00#########"));
```

Output:

```
50.00
50.010101
```

(Like suggested in comments by "Alex" and "Erno de Weerd")

Answer (score 3):

You could use [TrimEnd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend(v=vs.110).aspx) to remove the last zeros like this:

```
decimal num = 50.01011000m;

if (num % 1 == 0)
{
    return num.ToString("0.00", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}       
string str = num.ToString().TrimEnd('0');

Console.WriteLine(str);
```

output:

> 50,01011

You could also pack it into an extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string ToTrimmendString(this decimal num)
    {
        if (num % 1 == 0)
        {
            return num.ToString("0.00", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
        return num.ToString().TrimEnd('0');
    }
}
```

and call it like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(num.ToTrimmendString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
    double num = 50.010110000;
    Console.WriteLine(num.ToString("0.0000", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) );
```

Please see this for more info https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#SpecifierPt`

Comment: `50.00000000` would result in `50.0000`. Not the expected `50.00`.

Comment: So you have to vary the format string as per your requirement , so if you want only 2 decimal places you will have to use num.ToString("0.00....

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this

```
public decimal removeTrailingZeros(decimal val)
{
    return val % 1 == 0 ? Math.Round(val, 2) : val / 1.0000000000000000000000000000000000m;
}
```

test input

50.00000000m,
50.01000000m,
50.01010000m,
50.01011000m,
50.01010100m,

output

50.00
50.01
50.0101
50.01011
50.010101

Comment: Why would this work?

Comment: because is how division between decimal numbers works

Comment: 50 != 50.00 as desired.

Comment: @Magnus edited, not as i clean as i  wanted but will do the trick

Comment: Seems a little bit overkill compared to the use of `ToString(0.00####)`...

Comment: @benichka true, but in this way, he will get a decimal back and not string as another answers suggested